# Storing a boolean bit for a many-to-many relation

Tags: ruby, database-design, sequel

I'm writing a forum system (in Ruby, using Sequel), and one of the requirements is for users to be able to "star" a thread, which is vaguely equivalent to "subscription" features most forums support. I'm unsure about how to store the starring in the database, and especially on how to query for starred/unstarred threads for a given user, or checking whether a thread is starred.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, and if you happen to know your way around Sequel, an example model would be absolutely grand.

Comment: A table named "STARS" with USER_ID and THREAD_ID should do it.

Comment: and maybe a date time so you can know if the star was added before or after content of the started thread changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple to implement:

### First your migration:

```
create_table(:subscriptions, ignore_index_errors: true) do
  primary_key :id
  column :created_at, 'timestamp with time zone'
  foreign_key :user_id, :users, null: false, key: [:id], index: true, on_delete: :cascade
  foreign_key :thread_id, :threads, null: false, key: [:id], index: true, on_delete: :cascade
end
```

### Your Models:

#### app/models/subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < Sequel::Model
  many_to_one :user
  many_to_one :thread
end
```

#### app/models/user.rb

```
class User < Sequel::Model
  one_to_many :subscriptions

  many_to_many :subscribed_threads,
    class:      :Thread,
    join_table: :subscriptions,
    left_key:   :user_id,
    right_key:  :thread_id
end
```

#### app/models/thread.rb

```
class Thread < Sequel::Model
  one_to_many :subscriptions

  many_to_many :subscribers,
    class:      :User,
    join_table: :subscriptions,
    left_key:   :thread_id,
    right_key:  :user_id
end
```

#### Query as follows

```
# all threads a user is subscribed to
user.subscribed_threads

# all subscribers to a thread
thread.subscribers

# all subscriptions to a thread in the last 3 days
thread.subscriptions.where{created_at >= Date.today - 3}
```

I suggest also configuring the dataset associations plugin on all your models:

```
# Make all model subclasses create association methods for datasets
Sequel::Model.plugin :dataset_associations
```

You can then compose and chain queries through associations with conditions more conveniently:

```
 # all new subscribers for a thread in the last 3 days who are moderators
thread.subscriptions.where{created_at >= Date.today - 3}.user.where(moderator: true)
```

There are some powerful filtering and querying possibilities:

- http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/dataset_filtering_rdoc.html
- http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/querying_rdoc.html